# Override abstract method as nullable both reference and value type

Tags: c#, abstract-class, c#-10.0

I use C# 10 and I have an generic abstract class. This abstract class implemented by 2 other classes which one uses reference type and the other uses value type.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T> {
    public abstract T? AbstractNullableTestMethod();
    public abstract T AbstractNotNullableTestMethod();
}

public class A : BaseClass<int> {
    public override int AbstractNotNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override int? AbstractNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
public class B : BaseClass<string> {
    public override string AbstractNotNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override string? AbstractNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

In this example, I get an error for class A. Because `int` is not null so I get `return type must be int` error for `AbstractNullableTestMethod` method. If I add `where T : struct` constraint this time class B get error because `string` is reference type.

The abstract class has multiple method, some of nullable, the others not. However, it can be implemented by reference type and value type generics.

Comment: This hasn't been possible allll the way back to C# 2, which introduced nullable value types. C# 9 just makes it *look* as though it's possible now by allowing `T?` to appear unconstrained, but since it's "just" an annotation and not a true part of the runtime type, the end result is still that it's impossible to do this with a single type. If nullability had been a prominent part of the language since the beginning things would have been very different, but then hindsight is 20-20. They did add the `where T : default` syntax to at least enable this for individual methods, but not whole types.

Comment: Yes, comment is right. I wish apply `where T: default` on class or some non generic methods inside generic class.

Comment: The closest you can get here, not with regards to implementation but intent, is to make both methods return `T` but mark the first method as `[return:NotNull]`. This forces `A` to override with `[return:NotNull] int?` with full warnings if the code might be wrong, and allows callers to write `(int) a.NotNullable....` or `NotNullable...().Value` without getting a warning. Treating the fact that we're dealing with a `Nullable` cannot be done transparently (`A` must implement `BaseClass<int?>`), since the runtime won't do it for us.

Comment: @is_oz Could you clarify about how to use the base class?

Comment: @shingo it is an abstract layer for services. Some of services has Guid identifier, some of int or long, the others have string.

Comment: An acceptable compromise might be to use the `default` value to indicate "no service", rather than `null` (you can translate `null` to `default` and vice versa at the edges of the system, where needed). You can even turn this into a virtue by implementing a `NullService` of some kind that either does nothing, or throws exceptions when an attempt is made to use its methods -- this is more informative than getting a `NullReferenceException`. This service could have a `T?` identifier.

Answer (score 2):

I can't provide you the answer you're looking for, but I can try to explain why it's not possible.

The ability to add these annotations (e.g. `T?`) was added in C# 9, the feature was called [unconstrained type parameter annotations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-9.0/unconstrained-type-parameter-annotations). The key points:

- If a type parameter `T` is substituted with a reference type, then `T?` represents a nullable instance of that reference type.
- If `T` is substituted with a value type, then `T?` represents an instance of `T`

The linked [design meeting notes](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/main/meetings/2019/LDM-2019-11-25.md#problem-1-t-and-t-mean-different-things) highlights the problem here, it's that there are now two different meanings for `T?` depending on whether `T` is constrained or not:

- unconstrained, it means 'the type of `default(T)`' (so where `T` is `int`, `T?` is also `int`)
- constrained to `struct` it means `Nullable<T>` (so `int?`)

They proposed two options to solve this problem, and the one they went with was evidently *'Live with problem 1, and try to explain things as best we can.'*

Comment: They put in a little more effort than that: part of the solution was also "introduce the `where T : default` syntax to allow generic method overrides to actually say what they want the constraint to mean". Annoyingly, if you're instantiating the parameter with a value type it becomes *unambiguous* what the constraint should mean, so this problem doesn't arise, but of course this feature was not intended to fix the more fundamental incompatibility between `Nullable<T>` and reference types (and indeed it cannot, now, without breaking backwards compatibility).

Comment: @Charles Mager, Yes I see the meeting note. I asked the question because I am moving to C# 10 from C# 7.3. Then I may miss something about technique. I read all documentation as possible about constraint. If I found a clear solution, I would apply it.

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the question mark in the override method.

```
public override int AbstractNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
```

You may know that in C# `int?` is short for `Nullable<int>` which is still a value type, but `string?` is equivalent to `string`. so if you wanna declare a method that returns a nullable value type, the type parameter declaration should be:

```
public class A : BaseClass<int?> {
    public override int? AbstractNotNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
    public override int? AbstractNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

Comment: If I write `int?`, that time I cannot use not nullable `int`  I need to use both of them. And also both of `string` and `int`. Your example is not what I want.

Comment: I think the intention is that this behaves the same way for value types as for reference types, which it doesn't in the original example. I don't think what's wanted is actually possible, though.

Answer (score 0):

Hint :- Since one type is null and another non null , you can use two generic type parameters. Please try.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T, Tnullable>
{
  public abstract Tnullable? AbstractNullableTestMethod();
  public abstract T AbstractNotNullableTestMethod();
}

public class A : BaseClass<int, int?>
{
  public override int AbstractNotNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
  public override int? AbstractNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();

}

public class B : BaseClass<string, string?>
{
  public override string AbstractNotNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
  public override string? AbstractNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();

}
```

If above implementation is not allowed in your project you have to adjust your base class.  Note that a non reference type can't be nullable and non nullable at the same context. Please find below code snippet.

```
public abstract class BaseClass<T>
{
  public virtual T? AbstractNullableTestMethod()
  {
    throw new NotImplementedException();
  }
  public abstract T AbstractNotNullableTestMethod();
}

public class A : BaseClass<int>
{
  public override int AbstractNotNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();

}

public class C : BaseClass<int?>
{
  public override int? AbstractNotNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
  
}

public class B : BaseClass<string>
{
  public override string AbstractNotNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();
  public override string? AbstractNullableTestMethod() => throw new NotImplementedException();

}
```

Comment: Thanks for hint, however it is not possible in the project.

Comment: yaa , I understand your project constraint . How can a non reference  type can  null and non null at the same time , that is not possible right . So if the above implementation is not allowed you have to adjust your abstract class with a default implementation for AbstractNullableTestMethod()  , So Class A  can avoid int? implementation. This is a design issue.